# How to evaluate truth value of quantified formula?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Using the truth table for the predicate $P$ over the domain $D=\{a,b,c\}$, where the first argument is the row of our truth table and the second is the column.  For example, $P(b,c) = F$, whereas $P(c,b) = T$.

[image]

Evaluate the truth values of the following predicate logic statement.

$$\exists x \forall y, P(y,x)$$

Comment: What exactly is the difficulty with this? Try to express the statement in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Putting your statement into words: "exists a column such that its intersection with all rows is True". No column meets the condition, so the statement is False.